# How to make sweetAlert (swal) behave like the regular js alert function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, javascript-objects, sweetalert

I am trying to make a "sweetalert2" box appear when the number of coins in a running game is 20. (I want to let the user know that they have reached 20 coins). If I just used alert, an alert box appears and the game pauses. However, I want to use the sweetalert box for better looks, but even when the box appears, the game still goes on running. How do I stop the game when the sweetalert box appears? The alert function handles this perfectly but it will be too plain for the game.
Here is the sweetalert code that I have:

```
swal({
 allowOutsideClick: false,
  title: 'You have 20 coins',
  html:
    '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input">' +
    '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input">',
  preConfirm: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      resolve([
        $('#swal-input1').val(),
        $('#swal-input2').val()
      ])
    })
  },
  onOpen: function () {
    $('#swal-input1').focus()
  }
}).then(function (result) {
  swal(JSON.stringify(result))
}).catch(swal.noop)
```

Comment: You need to add logic to your game that allows you to pause it programatically. You can't make the sweetalert popup block the thread to pause your game like the browser `alert` method does

Comment: You might find using `async`/`await` here useful if you want to stop the code directly below the sweetalert popup from running while the alert is open. But this won't stop other code outside of your `async` function from running while the alert is open (eg: a game loop for instance would still run)